# Generate a trained model on number series and identify the next number

Tags: python, machine-learning, numbers, training-data

I want to create a model in which i will be passing a number series and it will identify the series pattern and will generate the next value.

ex: `Input: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 ,16.....200`

Above is my input, my model will identify itself that it's a `2x` series and will give `202, 204,....` as output.

Can this be done using an `machine learning` algorithm?

Comment: This is way too broad, and not specific to any scope of machine-learning, python. Please try to limit your question to something specific. That said, the simple answer is "yes" you can use many different models.

Comment: It can be done, search for `timeseries`, and have fun

Comment: @PV8 I have tried with timeseries but I am getting result in fractions and with very poor accuracy.  I have used Sequential() function for this. Do you have any specific algorithm? or any particular reference. Your help matters a lot.

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky Thanks . Can you mention any specific algorithm or any link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic model I created for your case:

```
import numpy as np
def models(array):
    if (array[2] - array[1]) == (array[-1] - array[-2]):
        desc = "Model is linear"
        val = array[-1] + (array[2] - array[1])
    elif (array[2] / array[1]) == (array[-1] / array[-2]):
        desc = "Model is exponential"
        val = array[-1] * (array[2]/array[1])
    else: 
        desc = "Model is not linear nor exponential"
        val = np.nan
    return desc, val
```

Here I am trying it:

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(models(c))
```

Output (should be 6):

```
('Model is linear', 6)
```

Another attempt with different numbers:

```
c = [2,4,8,16,32]
print(models(c))
```

Output (should be 64):

```
('Model is exponential', 64.0)
```

Regardless of this particular case, you should try and find Machine Learning courses to understand what can you achieve with machine learning and learn how to program an actual machine learning model. Otheriwse the scope is just too wide.

Comment: thanks for your effort. Yeah its a too broad concept because a series can be ascending or descending or uneven. Algorithm like this will not help much. I have read somewhere about RNN, have any idea about it? Does it work on series?

Comment: Yes, you can make it work on a Series, but I would realy recommend you start studying these concepts and then limit your question to a specific issue.